# What are the supported return types for Google App Engine Endpoints for Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I would like to know whether I could return a pdf as a response to Google App Engine Endpoints for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Responses from Google Cloud Endpoints APIs must be of content-type application/json. You could bundle the binary data of the PDF in a JSON value by encoding it with base64.